# Does Electromagnetic Inertia has any relation with the emission of Electromagnetic Waves from Accelerated Charged Particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics

We know that Electromagnetic Fields have certain inertia in them. Lenz's Law is a good example to demonstrate Electromagnetic Inertia. Nature resists the change in the state of Electromagnetic Fields in space. I somehow have this Intuition, without justified mathematics or logic, that accelerating charged particles in space giving rise to Electromagnetic Waves, could also be having some relation with the idea of Electromagnetic Inertia. I just wish to confirm the validity this Intuition and if possible wish to receive some more guidance on the same. 
I feel, since nature doesn't like the change in the state of electromagnetic fields in space, so when an accelerated charged particle tries to change that state of electromagnetic fields in space, so nature develops this mechanism of emission of electromagnetic waves, so as to resist this change. 
Any more guidance on this thought is very welcome. 
Intuitive answers are more welcome.

Comment: There are ways to make the inertia analogy, by stating that inertia is really the conservation of momentum, and then you would have the Poynting vector as a repository of momentum. What would really be interesting is to calculate the Poynting vector for a uniformly moving charge—it is almost surely not zero!

Answer (score 1):

This should not be viewed as a guidance, but here is how one can think about it.

We can say that something has changed only if we can detect or measure that change.

For something to be detected, it has to impart some energy, which implies that some work has to be done to create that energy.

As an example, we can learn that a charge is moving some distance away by detecting the EM wave it has produced.

The wave has to impart some energy on the sensor and it gets this energy from the charge. Therefore, the change needs to perform some work to generate the wave.

The "inertia" we feel when speeding up the charge is due to the force and work required to create or change the field and generate that wave.